# The embedded Derby DB to access with multiple clients

Tags: hibernate, java-8, derby, embedded-database, spring-orm

I write **Java SE 8** based, desktop application. Its got **Derby DB** (v10.13.1.1) which comes together with my app. I use the **Hibernate ORM** framework (v5.2.10.Final) for the communication with the DB, and the **Spring** framework (spring-orm @ v4.3.7.RELEASE), which contributes to it too.

If I run my app as a single instance at a time, all is good- the DB causes no problems. But if I create multiple instances of the application, or at the same time access the DB with the DB client, DBeaver, it causes following exception:

```
[AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG (124 : 2017-07-28 22:14:57,245) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Unable to acquire JDBC Connection [n/a]
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'M_Vezelis_Draw_DB_1_6v.db' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:521)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:448)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.getProjectDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.mindaugas.vezelis.gui.MainGUI$4.actionPerformed(MainGUI.java:415)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'M_Vezelis_Draw_DB_1_6v.db' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database F:\Aristotelis\J-A-V-A\Java\M-Vezelis-Draw\M_Vezelis_Draw_DB_1_6v.db.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.privGetJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.getJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    ... 67 more
[AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN  (129 : 2017-07-28 22:14:57,246) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - SQL Error: 40000, SQLState: XJ040
[AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR (131 : 2017-07-28 22:14:57,247) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Failed to start database 'M_Vezelis_Draw_DB_1_6v.db' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93, see the next exception for details.
[AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN  (129 : 2017-07-28 22:14:57,247) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - SQL Error: 45000, SQLState: XSDB6
[AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR (131 : 2017-07-28 22:14:57,247) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database F:\Aristotelis\J-A-V-A\Java\M-Vezelis-Draw\M_Vezelis_Draw_DB_1_6v.db.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:542)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.getProjectDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.mindaugas.vezelis.gui.MainGUI$4.actionPerformed(MainGUI.java:415)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:521)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:448)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'M_Vezelis_Draw_DB_1_6v.db' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:115)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'M_Vezelis_Draw_DB_1_6v.db' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93, see the next exception for details.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database F:\Aristotelis\J-A-V-A\Java\M-Vezelis-Draw\M_Vezelis_Draw_DB_1_6v.db.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.privGetJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.getJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
    ... 67 more
```

The cause of the exception is the:

```
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database
```

So, the DB connection is set-up as **embedded**, because the DB is used as embedded to the app.
What is a work around?

- Should the DB be set-up as a service provider to clients?
- Any configurations (DB vs. Hibernate and Spring)?

When it comes to configuring the connection to the DB, the embedded way sets-up smoothly. Whereas the server type always ends-up with a glitch, meaning that the communication gets rejected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot share Derby DB **files** among multiple JVMs. The first JVM to create or connect to existing DB will lock the files to itself so that no data corruption can occur.

You have two choices:

- embed your database into just one app that resides in a single JVM end expose higher level API to work with it either via REST or via event bus (or both)
- start [Derby as a server](https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html), then the architecture looks like this:

> [image: Derby DB running as a server]

The second approach might is easier to achieve (less coding), and the URL for JDBC or Hibernate will look like `jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/derbyDB` 
You need, of course, create the database first, for which you need to connect *once* with  `jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/derbyDB?create=true`. You should not use `create=true in Hibernate pool. Just do this:

```
try (Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:derbyDB;create=true")) {
    System.out.println("Database created: "+c);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); //adapt it to your logging/error processing
}
```

The code above prints something like:

```
Database created: org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection@105374791 (XID = 167), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = derbyDB), (DRDAID = null)
```

The first approach, with single embedded app and external interface, allows you to control the resources and access much better, though. If you are going for efficiency/speed, the time spent might be well worth it.

All that said, if single embedded Derby is not enough, developers usually look for other options, e.g. PostgreSQL. Even "DB2 Express C" could be an option to ship with your app. It really depends on the use case.